# Push of stack not inserting the new value - C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, stack

```
void push(stack *head, int valuee)
{
    if(head->next==NULL && head->value==-1)
    {
        head->value = valuee;
        printf("First element %d inserted\n",valuee);
    }
    else
    {
        stack *temp = new stack;
        temp->value = valuee;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        printf("Element %d inserted\n",valuee);
    }
}
```

First element is inserted properly but when i continue inserting elements, none of the elements are inserted after the first one.
Read somewhere that i have to pass pointer to pointer of stack but I did this same thing during a postfix infix question and it was working over there.
Help me with this problem here.
Many thanks for any help in advance

Previous example of infix postfix which was working fiine

```
void push(char c, stack *node)
{
    stack *B = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (node->next == NULL)
    {
        node->next = B;
        B->value = c;
        B->next =NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        B->next = node->next;
        node->next = B;
        B->value = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just point head to the new node every time. If you want to push you need to update the links. new_node->what_head_is_pointing_to_now, then head->new_node, right now you have a memory leak. Also `new` is a C++ key word, if this is really C code that should be a malloc, or you should update your tags

Comment: @Mike by -> you mean =. right?
but i did the same thing by doing this temp->next = head; and 
head = temp;

Comment: @Mike thnx. i updated new to malloc and it worked. But how did this happen? I mean i am compiling with code block and saving the file as .cpp  also, then why using the new command giving the wrong answer??

Comment: You should also note that as the code is, if `head` is `NULL`, you'll have a segfault in the first `if` statement.

Comment: @kfb thnx but dat wont happen because i have put an extra check for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the function like this

```
    stack* push(stack *head, int valuee)
    //return void to stack * 
    return head;
    //In the end return the new head
```

and it will work.
Call push like this

```
head = push(head,value);
```

Comment: nice, this is much simpler than my answer... haha

Comment: thanx kunal but how was this thing working previously for me. There also I was doing i the same and using malloc instead of new but it was working over there

Comment: I have edited the question with my previous version of infix postfix also.

Comment: the approach is different in both the samples that you have provided...in case 1 you are trying to assign temp->next = head and head = temp, which will be good for stack implementation,but since it considers it is called by value after returning it shows invalid values for next node

Comment: I understood your point. Thanx for pointing it out.
Correct me if I am wrong.
In case 1, I am changing the local variable head of push whereas in the other case I am changing a reference value whose change will be reflected in the original stack

Comment: I think in the second case it shows undefined behavior because in first call B is assigned to node->next which is incorrect when considering implementation of stack so the head->next->next points to undefined value and from then in the next call same thing happens which was happening in your previous code..

Answer (score 1):

Why u need pointer to pointer ?

You want to modify the contents of a pointer so if you pass only a pointer to the function it is pass by copy so you can not modify it actually.

In the case of infix-prefix scenario you must have not modified the string you would have read it only, so a pointer to pointer is not required.

Comment: o i was was doing the same thing over there also, ie, inserting char instead of int.

I have edited the question with my previous infix version also

Answer (score 1):

For this line of code in the `else` portion of the `if` statement:

```
    head = temp;
```

Your intention is to mutate `head`, in other words, change what `head` is pointing to. However, pointers are passed in as values, just like other variables. In other words, suppose I call the `push` function somewhere else. For simplicity, suppose I call it in the `main` function, something like this:

```
int main()
{
    stack *headOfStack = new stack;
    // suppose this next push triggers the else portion of the push code
    push(headOfStack, 6);
}
```

Now, after the `push(headOfStack, 6);` statement has been executed, your intention is to expect `headOfStack` to point to a new "stack node" which contains the value `6`. Now, `headOfStack` is a pointer to a variable of type stack. It stores a memory address. You can think of a memory address as some integer. When we call `push`, we are copying the **content** of `headOfStack` (the content of `headOfStack` is a memory address) into the **local variable** `head` of the `push` function. Therefore, when:

```
head = temp;
```

is executed, we are assigning the contents of `temp` to `head`. What is `temp`? It is a pointer to a variable of type `stack`. In other words, the value of `temp` is a memory address. So `head = temp;` simply assigns the memory address contained in `temp` to the local variable `head`. The local variable `head` in the `push` function and our `headOfStack` variable in the `main` function are two **completely different** variables with different memory addresses. If my explanation has been clear so far, this means that when we modify `head` in the `push` function, the `headOfStack` variable in `main` is totally unchanged.

What you want to do in this case is:

```
void push(stack **headPtr, int valuee)
{
    // this will get the actual pointer we are interested in
    stack *head = *headPtr;
    if(head->next==NULL && head->value==-1)
    {
        head->value = valuee;
        printf("First element %d inserted\n",valuee);
    }
    else
    {
        stack *temp = new stack;
        temp->value = valuee;
        temp->next = head;
        // mutation is done here
        *headPtr = temp;
        printf("Element %d inserted\n",valuee);
    }
}
```

And its usage, using our fictional `main` function:

```
int main()
{
    stack *headOfStack = new stack;
    // notice the use of &headOfStack instead of headOfStack
    push(&headOfStack, 6);
}
```

Just remember that pointers store memory addresses, and that pointers are just variables, and they have memory addresses as well. To mutate a pointer (change what a pointer is pointing to), just pass in its memory address to the function.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT for new edit in question**

```
void push(char c, stack *node)
{
    stack *B = (stack *)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    if (node->next == NULL)
    {
        node->next = B;
        B->value = c;
        B->next =NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        B->next = node->next;
        node->next = B;
        B->value = c;
    }
}
```

For this version of `push`, what it's doing is essentially:

1. If `node->next == NULL`, so `node` has no successor, then set its successor to a newly allocated node with value `c`
2. Otherwise, `node->next != NULL` and `node` has some successor. Then we would set the newly allocated node `B` to `node`'s successor, and set `node`'s original successor to be `B`'s successor. Or in other words, it splices a new node `B` (with value `c`) in between `node` and its successor.

I am finding it quite hard to explain this, but a simple explanation is, this `push` does not change what `node` is pointing to. At nowhere did we show intention to mutate `node`. I think the stuff involving `B` should be quite understandable, so let's focus on the `node->next` assignments.

I am assuming that the `stack` is a struct that looks something like this:

```
struct stack {
    char value;
    struct stack *next;
};
```

Now, suppose in our `main` function, we have a `stack`:

```
stack x;
```

Notice that `x` is not a pointer. I think we all agree that doing `x.value = something` and `x.next = something` will mutate those fields.

Now, let's look at this:

```
stack *y = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```

We know that `y` stores an address to an actual `struct stack` (the actual `struct stack` is at `*y`). So `y->value = something` and `y->next = something` will mutate those fields.

So hopefully you can see why the `node->value` assignments work. Essentially `node` contains an address to an actual `struct stack`, whose value is `*node`. By pointer syntax, `node->value` and `node->next` assignments will change the contents of `node`.

Not a very good explanation I know. But just write more code. Pointers confused the hell out of me when I was first starting out with C. I think that these days, I can still be confused by 2 or 3 layers of indirection, and I've encountered some very nasty pointer bugs. Just practice more... some day you will really get it. I know it's what they all say, but it's true.

Comment: although kunal gave a simpler answer but this one cleared my concept. Very thanks for answering in detail.
But still I have one doubt that how was this thing working previously for me. There also I was doing i the same and using malloc instead of new but it was working over there

Comment: I have edited the question with my previous version of infix postfix also.

Comment: i will add a section below my answer to explain to you your newly added code

Comment: thanx a lot.
I understood it know. I am changing the local variable head of push function in the 1st case whereas in this new case, I am changing a value referenced by node->next whose change will be reflected in the original stack also.